# Send data from third party to my server and return data

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, session, cross-domain

I'm trying to make a login system from third party. 
A third part site will send me a request and I will grab my `$_session['id']` (the userid of currently logged in user to my website)  and return it back to third party Ajax request.

**Third-party.com/home.Php**

```
$. Post(www.mywebsite.com/logindata.php, 
{ appid :appid}, function(data) {// DO SOMETHING
});
```

**Mywebsite.com/logindata.php**

```
//header to allow control origin 

echo $_Session['id'] ;
```

Now my problem is even if the `$_session` is not empty it shows empty when doing cross origin requests.

***PS:** the session shows some value when I'm trying to open the login ‘data.php’ directly from browser.*

I tried to think of different way and instead of sending a `$. post` request to *mywebsite.com/logindata.php.*  I did `window.open(mywebsite.com/logindata.php)` and now the session value is working fine but I don't know how to return it back to the third-party. Com/home.php page.

***PS:** the feature I'm trying to make is similar to open login system of Google. Like "signup with google".*

Any idea on how to achieve it?  *(I'm not concerned about security at the moment)*

Comment: I think I got it I need to use Oauth2

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got the problem (question) right but I remember using "echo json_encode( $data )" to send a reply back to ajax post and Parse Json on the receiver side.